# How to write GetEnumerator() for a generic class?

Tags: c#, ienumerator

I have a generic class in my program. Then I want to use an instance of `class<T>` in a `foreach` loop, but it needs to use a public `GetEnumerator`. How can I write a `GetEnumerator()` for `foreach`?

```
public class ReadStruct<T> where T : struct
{
            MemoryTributary _ms = null;
            public ReadStruct(MemoryTributary ms)
            {
                _ms = ms;
            }

            public T this[int Index]
            {
                get
                {
                    if (Index < Count)
                        return   _ms.Read<T>(Index);
                    return new T();
                }
            }

            public int CountByteToStruct { get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)); } }
            public long Count { get { return _ms.Length / CountByteToStruct; } }
            // it doesn't work!!   
            public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return (IEnumerator<T>)this;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Implement `IEnumerable<T>`, it's not *mandatory* for use in `foreach` but it's best practice so you can cast your struct to `IEnumerable<T>` and get extension method support:

  ```
  public class ReadStruct<T> : IEnumerable<T>
      where T : struct
  ```
- Then you can implement `GetEnumerator` using `yield return` and reusing your indexer:

  ```
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
      var count = Count;
      for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
          yield return this[i];
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for answer tommorow I'll check it. And sorry for my English I only study it.